# Azure pipeline execution timeout

Tags: sql, azure-devops, timeout, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am running Azure Devops pipeline and this pipeline calls a SQL procedure.

1. This procedure takes more than 6 hours to complete (it takes around 10 hours)
2. After procedure execution, I will take a database backup (it takes around 12 hours)

The problem which I'm facing is pipeline execution throws error after 6 hours:

> Not received any response, or we stopped hearing from Agent Azure Pipelines 4. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error. For more information

We have proper networks and no issues in procedure.

I have done the below setup still same problem

```
timeout to 0 & 7600
timeout to 7600
Number of retries if task fail to 5
```

Please let me know

1. how to make pipeline to wait until SQL procedure complete
2. how to catch SQL exception to stop pipeline execution. currently the pipeline status updates with success status even if any errors occurs in SQL

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: About catching SQL exception, how did you call a SQL procedure in pipeline? Could you please share more information?

Comment: If azure deployment pipeline stages fails with time out error any options available to continue with next stage ? I have tried with few option like continue with error, partial error etc all work if error occurs not on timeout error

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the Microsoft hosted agent, so the pipeline will be time out after 6 hours. Please refer this [Capabilities and limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations) for Microsoft-hosted agents:

> You can pay for additional capacity per parallel job. Paid parallel jobs remove the monthly time limit and allow you to run each job for up to 360 minutes (6 hours).

To resolve the time out issue, as your pipeline will run more than 6 hours, please consider to use a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install). Setting the [timeout value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts) to zero means that the job can run forever on self-hosted agents.

Comment: If azure deployment pipeline stages fails with time out error any options available to continue with next stage ? I have tried with few option like continue with error, partial error etc all work if error occurs not on timeout error

Comment: Hi I found you have created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949261/azure-devops-continue-on-time-out-error-in-pipeline-deployment. and in the comment someone has shared a solution. Please check . Thanks.